# stream processing watermark heuristics

Tags: spark-streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, spark-structured-streaming, stream-processing

How accurate are watermark estimates in stream processing in apache beam or spark streaming.
My data source are files from gcs/s3 , but i use event time associated with each event as the timestamp for windowing function. Any ideas on how is this heuristic or estimate calculated by these stream processing engines and if there is  way to measure how bad this estimate was.

My use case i have several server produceing event logs on gcs/S3 and then i am reading this files in a streaming way from my stream processing engine. So there can be delayed due to filesystem outages and failures or servers not being able to flush log events for couple hours. So In my stream processing pipeline correctness is one of the important aspect when aggregating some events. So I am curios how is this watermark estimate computed

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, watermark is determined by the source. When a source announces a watermark of T, it is saying "I don't expect any more records with eventtime earlier than T". The streaming engine can then proceed to close the related windows etc. There could still be some events that arrive with timestamp less than T, and those will be considered "late". In Apache Beam, you have control on such late events as well. Sources in Apache Beam provide watermark by implementing [getWatermark() interface](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.2.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/UnboundedSource.java#L218) (documentation there is quite helpful too).

In your case, critical part would be to know how delayed these files could be. You mentioned couple of hours. A simple heuristic could be keep watermark to `'latest event time - 2 hours'`. Based on expected distribution of delays, you could limit that to 10 minutes to get most of the benefit and treat further delayed events as 'late'.

Comment: I am already using a pre implemented source. My events are mobile app events that are being logged by servers into gcs buckets. So how does a filesystem source will have any idea about the latest timestamp of the events since all it sees is log file cretion time and no idea about the event timestamps within the logs

Comment: What is the source you are using? If you can, please point to sample code.

Comment: I don't think AvroIO supports unbounded reads for streaming application, it does not have a notion of a watermark (I was checking AvroIO.java).

Comment: I think you can read records in a streaming way using watchForNewFiles and then readAll

Comment: I know this can be done for FileIO for sure and then read file by file to be expanded into avro records

Comment: In other words, you are implementing an unbounded source using FileIO as a utility to find and fetch files. In that case you also need to implement 'getWatermark()' as linked above.

Comment: The watermark depends on the data source; in some cases, it is an estimate. In others, such as Pub/Sub with system-assigned timestamps, the watermark can provide an exact bound of what data the pipeline has processed.

Comment: @raghu : I thought this unboundedsource created by using fileIO ,has some default implmentation of estimating watermark ? If not , what is a good way to imolemnet this and what other methods do i need to implement to make sure this works correctly. I assumed that this was of streaming files from gcs is exactly once processing all of them so it already had some notion of watermark